# how can I create xml file common encryption using gpac?

Tags: xml

how I get cypher key, cipher IV, KID and KID value? I am not clear about BS ID128, BS value="2" and bits="32". what is the meaning of BS value="2" and bits="32" and string="CID=Toto". I know this clear about and how can I manually generate similar type xml file?

```xml
<key KID="0x12131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2021" value="0x25262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334"/>
```

Comment: Please may you make sure to edit the question with the XML and a [mcve] of what you have already tried? (Don't post the xml in the comments)

Comment: (Please do not post the xml in the comments)

Comment: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/Common-Encryption this procedure but i am not clear how can i generate kid and kid value also first_IV?

Comment: I read common encryption for gpac link given below github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/Common-Encryption. But I am not clear this procedure. How can i generate DRMInfo BS value="2" bits="32"  and CrypTrack KID and value ?